# What exactly is "source" in the context of Firebase rewrites?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I've read the Firebase documents and watched other tutorials multiple times and none of them explicitly explained what source was.
so in Layman's terms, what exactly is source in the context of the code below?

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/bigben",
    "function": "bigben"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: so... thanks to answers from others, I realize that source is just a URL .. but please help me because I'm dying to know... is the URL(the source) from a client-side user who's visiting my website?

Answer (score 2):

By declaring a **rewrite**, as follows

```
"rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/bigben",
    "function": "bigben"
  } ]
```

you actually "direct hosting requests to your function" as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_requests_to_function).

---

If you look at the documentation about how to [configuring the rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites), you will see that for

```
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/foo{,/**}",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
```

> The rewrites attribute contains an array of rewrite rules, where each
>   rule must include:
>
> - A **source** specifying a glob pattern
> - A **destination**, which is a local file that must exist

By doing

```
  "rewrites": [ {
    ...
    "function": "bigben"
  } ]
```

instead of

```
  "rewrites": [ {
    ...
    "destination": "...."
  } ]
```

you redirect **to the `bigben` function**, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_requests_to_function).

---

So, "in Layman's terms", the platform redirects incoming requests coming from one or more **sources** to one or more **destinations**, and, in your case, the destination is a Cloud Function.

Comment: "A source specifying a glob pattern" -> I know what a glob pattern is but what's the purpose of specifying a glob pattern there? Why does it need to specify a glob pattern?

Comment: "coming from one or more sources" -> so what is source ? does it mean something different than the plain English word "source" such as a place or origin where things come from?

Comment: The `source` is essentially the path of the incoming URL.

Comment: @MikeKim It's difficult to understand what you don't understand! :-) A redirection redirects **from** an URL **to** another URL. The first one is the **source** URL and the second one is the destination URL. It is not exactly like "a place or origin where things come from", it is more like the original URL which is **replaced** by another URL (the destination), from the browser perspective.

Comment: hmmm I see... so source URL is from a client side user who's visiting my webpage right?

Answer (score 0):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions .

> Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to HTTPS requests. Your code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment. There's no need to manage and scale your own servers.
>
> For example use cases and samples for Cloud Functions integrated with Firebase Hosting, visit our serverless overview.